# Cannot insert action into sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I’m creating a List Workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010.  In the first step I have a conditional under which I am trying to add a Start Approval Process step:
[image: About to enter the next action...]
When I try to insert the next line, the blinking orange line pauses, then resumes blinking.  I get no error, but the action is never entered:
[image: Nothing happened.]
This is for a workflow on the dev server.  I'm attempting to mimic this working workflow in my own dev environment:
[image: It works on my machine.]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, SharePoint Designer 2010 needed to be restarted more than one time, and needed to wait a number of hours (approx. 15 hrs).  This action is working now.